# Save object before transaction ends in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am using the JbpmContext for transaction which is implemented in filter. I have servlet controller which is calling service methods and then DAO methods to persist objects. Servlet controller is handling rollback operation if any exception occurs. But in some cases, when exception fires still I want to persist particular field of particular object at service layer. I tried with session.flush(), but it was not working at all.

Let me give you an example

```
class servletController {

    public void doGet(request, response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        try {

            testService.test(object);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // rollback
        }
    }
}


class TestService {

    public void test(object) throws Exception {

        try {

            // Business logic. Here is the codes which throws some exception


        } catch(Exception e) {
            object.setFailed(true); // Any how, I want to persist this field
            session.save(object);
            session.flush(); 
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I have one solution like I can do it in seprate transaction but I don't want that.
So is there any other way to persist object before transaction ends ? 
I want to do it only at service layer.

Comment: What if the data is not stored in your catch block. Another query is that if any exception occurs then try to resolve it don't try to perform any operation can generate another exception for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vighanesh. Actually from business logic (here from test() method), I am calling method that checks whether resource is online or not, if not then throwing user defined exception. So I just swallowing that exception and updating object status to failed. I can achieve this from controller side by swallowing this particular user defined exception and keep away it from rollback part but its a big enterprise application and lots of other code rely on it. So I want to be go only with my suggested flow if someone have any solution for it.